# Qt 5 Multimedia. GStreamer errors

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. Qt 5.8.0. I wrote the code for playing music:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/radioactive.mp3"));
    player->setVolume(50);
    player->play();
```

I am getting an error:

```
Warning: "For type 'audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)1, mpegaudioversion=(int)1, layer=(int)3, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2, parsed=(boolean)true' no decoders available."
Error: "Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in."
```

I tried to install following packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Says that `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` is not found or is obsolete. Also I tried to completely reinstall GStreamer

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l gstreamer* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}') && sudo apt-get install gstreamer*
```

It didn't help. Maybe someone joined in with this problem. How I can solve this?

Comment: Qt Multimedia which did not work for me on embedded Linux and even not always on Desktop and made me to learn GStreamer and OpenCV. I am now able to use either of two plus Qt with QML to accomplish the task. IMHO the question maybe solvable, need to trace Qt code or/and spy on GStreamer but then many problems will surface. I guess without having access to your system plus quite a few time it is not worth it to try to answer. And BTW GStreamer 0.10 is very outdated. Current GStreamer complies with 1.0 and the version is near 1.7 or so. I suggest to have a look at QtGStreamer - not used myself.